# Why doesn't the cookie value get displayed

Tags: java, servlets, cookies, web-applications

We were given an exercise to convert letters to phone numbers. I have two servlets, one to read the input from a form and store the information in a session and a cookie (as instructed by our professor), the other servlet's job is to output the values stored inside the session object and the cookie. The problem is every time I input something it doesn't instantly show up.

Example:

Input: 0922-ABCDEFG | Output: -2223334 
Input2: 0912-ABCDEFG | Output: 0922-2223334
Input3: -ABCDEFG | Output: 0912-2223334
Input4: 0917-ABCDEFG | Output: - 2223334

Here's the code of the two servlets:

```
package com.telco.process;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class ConvertServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/Convert")
public class ConvertServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String num;
    private String telco;
    private HttpSession session;
    private Cookie cTelco;
    private RequestDispatcher rd;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        String convertedNum = "";
        session = request.getSession();
        num = request.getParameter("number");
        telco = request.getParameter("telco");
        rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("Display");

        if (num != null || num != "")
        {
            for (byte i = 0; i < num.length(); i++)
            {
                switch(num.charAt(i))
                {
                    case 'A':
                    case 'B':
                    case 'C': convertedNum += "2"; break;
                    case 'D': 
                    case 'E':
                    case 'F': convertedNum += "3"; break;
                    case 'G':
                    case 'H': 
                    case 'I': convertedNum += "4"; break;
                    case 'J':
                    case 'K':
                    case 'L': convertedNum += "5"; break;
                    case 'M':
                    case 'N':
                    case 'O': convertedNum += "6"; break;
                    case 'P':
                    case 'Q':
                    case 'R':
                    case 'S': convertedNum += "7"; break;
                    case 'T':
                    case 'U':
                    case 'V': convertedNum += "8"; break;
                    case 'W':
                    case 'X':
                    case 'Y':
                    case 'Z': convertedNum += "9"; break;
                }
            }

            session.setAttribute("number", convertedNum);
            cTelco = new Cookie("telco", telco);
            response.addCookie(cTelco);
        }
        rd.forward(request, response);
    }

}
```

Servlet 2:

```
package com.telco.process;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.Cookie;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/Display")
public class DisplayNumber extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter pw = response.getWriter();
        Cookie ck[] = request.getCookies();
        pw.println("The converted number is " + ck[1].getValue() + "-" + request.getSession(false).getAttribute("number")); 
    }
}
```

Comment: How would I investigate via HTTP? By using doGet instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should investigate from browser side : looks at HTTP headers sent.

Furthermore `Cookie ck[] = request.getCookies()` is an array but you are only displaying the second element `ck[1]`